# How to Configure PgAdmin4 to Use Apache2 from LAMPP?

Tags: apache, pgadmin-4, lampp

I installed LAMPP on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. I also installed PgAdmin4 to work with my Postgresql 14. The problem is, both LAMPP and PgAdmin4 installation came with their own Apache2. This cause error for me, as in the development process, I use `127.0.0.1/pgadmin4` and `localhost/` at browser interchangeably.

For now, each time I need to edit psql database in PgAdmin4, I need to turn off LAMPP using `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop` command and to turn on pgAdmin4 with `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start`. And vice-versa if I need to test the website output in LAMPP `localhost`.

Is there any way around them? How to configure pgAdmin4 to use Apache2 from LAMPP? Or to Install pgAdmin4 ***without the packaged Apache2***?

I already tried using PhpPgAdmin 7 instead, but it keeps getting error.

Comment: You can copy the content of pgadmin4 `wsgi` file  into existing one and restart apache service.

Comment: Please clarify: So I copy the content of ```wsgi``` file from the pgadmin4 to ```wsgi``` in LAMPP folder? I found no file correspond to wsgi in LAMPP except under name ```/opt/lampp/modules/mod_proxy_wsgi.so```

Comment: Yes copy the content of `wsgi` file from the pgadmin4 to existing Apache instance configuration. Basically merge the `wsgi` file or create Virtual directory.